# How to get data for a metric for 1 day of timegrain in azure powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I want 90 days azure metrics for vm with timegrain of 1 day i.e 24 hours.
Whem i am trying that it fails with error of bad request.

```
Get-AzureRMMetric -ResourceId $vm[0].Id -TimeGrain 24:00:00 -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -StartTime (Get-Date).adddays(-90) -EndTime (Get-Date)
```

Error is as follows

```
Get-AzureRMMetric : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseException: 
Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.MetricsOperations.<ListWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.MetricsOperationsExtensions.<ListAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Metrics.GetAzureRmMetricCommand.ProcessRecordInternal()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.MonitorCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet(), Code: Null, Status code:Null, Reason phrase: Null
At line:1 char:9
+ $metric=Get-AzureRMMetric -ResourceId $vm[0].Id -TimeGrain 24:00:00 - ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmMetric], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Metrics.GetAzureRmMetricCommand
```

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57922767/edit) your question and include the **full** error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for powershell -Timegrain is

```
d.HH:MM:ss
```

So to get a timespan of 1 day in your request, you would write

```
-TimeGrain 1.00:00:00
```

Hope this helps.
Regards, John.

Answer (score 0):

When it says **BadRequest**, most probably you must be passing some wrong arguments. I see, you are calling Id for passing resourceId, i suspect there might be some problem.

Please find the details as below which will be providing you the metric:

```
# Name of your VM or
$vmName = 'VM NAME'

# Get all the resources
$allResource = Get-AzureRmResource

# Filter your resource based on name
$specificVM= $allResource | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $vmName}
ECHO $specificVM

# Retrieve the data
$detail = Get-AzureRMMetric -ResourceId $specificVM.ResourceId -TimeGrain 24:00:00 -MetricName "Percentage CPU" -StartTime (Get-Date).adddays(-90) -EndTime (Get-Date)
ECHO $detail

# Get the data
ECHO $detail.Data
```

[image]

Comment: Resource ID is perfectly fine... when i enter time grain as 12:00:00 it works for me... but when i write it as 24:00:00 it fails... Though have you tested the code you have pasted does it work for you?

Comment: Check your Powershell and AzureRM module version. I am validating on PS Version-**5.1.17134.858** and AzureRM version-**5.7.0**.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me absolutly fine:

```
$ResourceId = <my resourceId>
(Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceI -TimeGrain 1.00:00:00).Data
```

**Output**

```
TimeStamp : 27.09.2021 13:25:00
Average   :
Minimum   :
Maximum   :
Total     : 8258
Count     :
```

Tested under PowerShell 7:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-Module -Name Az.Monitor

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Script     2.7.0                 Az.Monitor
```

If you want to have it for a specific day (let's say yesterday):

```
(Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $ResourceI -TimeGrain 1.00:00:00 -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Data
```